# In owl carousel how to navigate next and previous with a class

Tags: jquery-plugins, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) and `ddscrollspy` in that I wanted when I append a class called `selected` to highlight that section. When the `selected` class gets appended to the carousel item it should go to next item which hidden in carousel.....

Answer (score 0):

var owl = $nc("#your-div").data('owlCarousel');
  owl.goto(5)